# dynamic memory allocation to buffer

Tags: c++, null, buffer, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on visual c++. I am a beginner of c++ and i am in a strange situation  that i have "Contents" variable of type-

```
char FileContents[200000] ;
```

now i have taken a size of a file using sizeof operator like this

```
int SizeOfFile =Sizeof(File);
```

and now i have to copy the data of this file into "Contents" whch has array index 200000.Suppose i do so by

```
memcpy(FileContents,&File[0],SizeOfFile);
```

and i output the contents of "FileContents" into a file at any location(according to my wish) .
What i found is the file contents are displayed properly but as the contents of file are finished i have strange data like "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ". please see below-

```
</body>
    </html> //Here finshes the file and after that i have this kind of data as you see below
    ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..and so on until file ends.
```

and i know its due to memory allocation of char FileContents[200000] ; because the "SizeOfFile" is very small value and after its size i have strange "ÌÌÌÌÌ" and i don't want to see them . **What i want is the file which contains only the contents of "FileContents" nothing else**. And i **can't allocate** the memory of FileContents dynalically. because it has to be equal to the "SizeOfFile" which we are getting dynamically using Sizeof(File) .

What to do in this situtaion iin order to get rid of these "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ" values ? Any solution?

Comment: how exactly are you writing the array to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the array with zeroes, since its initial contents are undetermined and could contain any value:

```
// initialize with 0
char FileContents[200000] = {};
```

You can also set the elements to zero after initialization using [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
// set all elements to 0 after initialization
std::fill(FileContents, FileContents + 200000, 0);              // C++03 or C++11
std::fill(std::begin(FileContents), std::end(FileContents), 0); // C++11
```

When it comes to interpreting `char` array as strings, these are treated as null terminated strings, meaning the end of the string is marked by the first `0` found.

Comment: why you have used FileContents  in the second argument ?

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT the second argument is actually `FileContents + 200000`, which is one past the end of the array. This is required for `std::fill`. But the initialization option is the better one.

Comment: if i do std::fill(HtmlFileContents, SizeOfFile + 200000, 0); in my code it gives error and actually i am not using std:: any where in my program its very strange for me.any other solution istead of std:: ?

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT If you have arbitrary requirements like not using the standard library you should have stated that in the question. But the first solution here works fine, and does not require any standard library functions.

Comment: do you think that it will also work if i have OLECHAR HtmlFileContents[200000] ; instead of char FileContents[200000] ; ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to fill all data with `'\0'` chars.

So use this:

```
char FileContents[200000] = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

doing this worked  for me-

```
char FileContents[200000] ={0};
```

and do the same after it as i done before.